# indices not available in Kibana 4.1.1

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I have the following indices in elasticsearch:

```
health status index               pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
green  open   logstash-2016.06.07   5   1    1112010            0    573.2mb        286.8mb 
green  open   logstash-2016.06.08   5   1     367834            0    331.7mb        166.5mb 
green  open   metrics-2016-06-07    5   1       2062            0      2.5mb          1.2mb 
green  open   metrics-2016-06-08    5   1         92            0      447kb        223.5kb
```

However, in Kibana 4.1.1 I can only see the "logstash-" indices. When I go to settings>indices and try to create an index pattern for "metrics-*" I get the message:

```
Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching this pattern?
```

The strange thing is that we have another environment that is configured the same way, with the same ELK versions and the same indices and we can search the metrics indices fine in kibana in that environment. Any idea what would cause this behavior?

Comment: I should add that I can't seem to find any configuration differences between the two environments. They seem to be set up exactly the same.

Comment: Barking up the wrong tree. It turns out that the problem was DNS-related, we were pointing to an incorrect kibana instance. So...never mind.